# The following code with listiterator is running infinitely

Tags: java, collections, listiterator

I am trying to iterate through a list using listiterator using previous method. In the loop If I try to add elements using listiterator.add method the loop is getting iterated infinitely

I tried to debug the code but I couldn't find the exact reason

```
public static methodOne() {
    List l = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     l.add(i);
    }
    ListIterator li = l.listIterator();
    while(li.hasNext()) {
     li.next();
    }
    while(li.hasPrevious()) {
     Integer i = (Integer)li.previous();
     li.add(56);
    }
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

I expect the output to be 56,0,1,56,2,56,3,56,4,56,5

Answer (score 1):

Your last loop runs infinitely because you keep adding an element and checking if it *has previous*. Of course it has previous, the one that you just added.

You can achieve what you want by:-

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 5)
        .flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(56, i))
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

```
[56, 0, 56, 1, 56, 2, 56, 3, 56, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`ListIterator.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add-E-) you will see:

> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by `next()`, if any, and after the element that would be returned by `previous()`, if any. (If the list contains no elements, the new element becomes the sole element on the list.) The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to `next` would be unaffected, and **a subsequent call to `previous` would return the new element**. (This call increases by one the value that would be returned by a call to `nextIndex` or `previousIndex`.)

So, alternating calls to `previous()` and `add()` will keep insert values at the same position in the list, and hence will never end (until memory runs out).

To show what happens, try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40));
    ListIterator<Integer> listIter = list.listIterator(list.size());
    print(list, listIter); // Iterator is at end (after 40)

    System.out.println("previous(): " + listIter.previous()); // prints: 40
    print(list, listIter); // Iterator is between 30 and 40

    for (int i = 39; i >= 31; i--) {
        listIter.add(i);   System.out.printf("add(i)%n", i);
        print(list, listIter);

        System.out.println("previous(): " + listIter.previous());
        print(list, listIter);
    }
}
static void print(List<Integer> list, ListIterator<Integer> listIter) {
    for (Integer i : list)
        System.out.printf("%5d", i);
    System.out.printf("%n%" + (listIter.nextIndex() * 5 + 2) + "s%n", "^");
}
```

*Output*

```
   10   20   30   40
                     ^
previous(): 40
   10   20   30   40
                ^
add(i)
   10   20   30   39   40
                     ^
previous(): 39
   10   20   30   39   40
                ^
add(i)
   10   20   30   38   39   40
                     ^
previous(): 38
   10   20   30   38   39   40
                ^
add(i)
   10   20   30   37   38   39   40
                     ^
previous(): 37
   10   20   30   37   38   39   40
                ^
add(i)
   10   20   30   36   37   38   39   40
                     ^
previous(): 36
   10   20   30   36   37   38   39   40
                ^
add(i)
   10   20   30   35   36   37   38   39   40
                     ^
previous(): 35
   10   20   30   35   36   37   38   39   40
                ^
add(i)
   10   20   30   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
                     ^
previous(): 34
   10   20   30   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
                ^
add(i)
   10   20   30   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
                     ^
previous(): 33
   10   20   30   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
                ^
add(i)
   10   20   30   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
                     ^
previous(): 32
   10   20   30   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
                ^
add(i)
   10   20   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
                     ^
previous(): 31
   10   20   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
                ^
```